# Why isn't the stack trace available, when exceptions are raised, in WLST (wls12.1.1)

Tags: jython, wlst

I've created a script to do *stuff* in the Online mode, for weblogic server 12.1.1.

I obviously messed something up, and i'd like to have the stack trace so that i can analyze what went wrong.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
try:
    connect("user","pass","t3://localhost:7001")
    messThingsUp()
except:
    dumpStack()
    rollback()
```

Instead of a stack trace i get:
"No stack trace available".

Please help

Thx, you guys rule!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I ended up using this code:

```
except Exception, inst:
    print('some diagnostic message here')
    print inst
    print sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Comment: lol, thx :) eventually i got along without it, and in the mean time i changed jobs :P But thx for the input, and have fun oveflowing stacks :)